# CSS mouse hover button color changes

Tags: html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/U4EF8/8/). I am trying mouse hover style which is working fine when i am dragging my mouse over button. But i dont want to drag my mouse over the button to change the color of the button text what i want is when i move my mouse inside the wrapper div which is a main div and inside that div all elements are set then text color of the button should change along with the mouse cursor .

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <p class="copyrights" id="copyrights">*Disclaimer</p>
        <div>
            <img id="Image_Car" src="http://i.share.pho.to/de4502fd_o.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="headlineText">
            <p id="headline1Txt" >Sample bag1</p>
            <p id="headline2Txt" >Sale Price $25</p>
            <p id="headline3Txt" >Sale $14<p>
        </div>
        <div id="disclaimer" >
            Details*
        </div>
        <div id="Image_logo">
            <img id="Imglogo" src="http://i.share.pho.to/88b65e5c_o.png" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  id="ctaBtn">
                <div id="fadeIn" >  Learn More Now </div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Why don't you set your hover listener on the element you want the hover to take effect, and then change the element your want to change inside?

Comment: Adding on to the above comment, what is *all elements are set*? Are you saying there needs to be some extra data level checks before changing colors?

Comment: That you want http://jsfiddle.net/U4EF8/9/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**css change**

```
#wrapper:hover .btn-primary,
.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active,.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled]{color:#ffffff;background-color:#0d2a4d;}
#wrapper:hover .btn{color:#DCDCDC;text-decoration:none;background-position:0 -15px;-webkit-transition:background-position 0.1s linear;-moz-transition:background-position 0.1s linear;-o-transition:background-position 0.1s linear;transition:background-position 0.1s linear;}
```

[Working Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4EF8/10/)

Comment: thats perfect how can i add hand cursor as well?/

Comment: if everything is working mark the answer as working so others can find it

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
#wrapper:hover .btn-primary{
    color:#DCDCDC;
    background-color:#0d2a4d;
    text-decoration:none;background-position:0 -15px;-webkit-transition:background-position 0.1s linear;-moz-transition:background-position 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition:background-position 0.1s linear;transition:background-position 0.1s linear;
}
```

this mean when the #wrapper getting hover , the btn-primary should take the belowes css.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U4EF8/13/)